# use the Dbus package in an electron app (Build process)

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, electron, dbus

i have this problem when i require `DBus` from the `dbus` package

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require("electron");
const DBus = require('dbus');

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    var win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 600, height: 500 });
    win.loadFile('index.html');

    win.webContents.openDevTools();
});
```

so when i execute this code i get this error :

```
> electron script.js

App threw an error during load
Error: Module did not self-register: '/home/bislem/projects/test/electron/node_modules/dbus/build/Release/dbus.node'.
    at process.func [as dlopen] (electron/js2c/asar.js:140:31)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1196:18)
    at Object.func [as .node] (electron/js2c/asar.js:140:31)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:981:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:881:14)
    at Function.Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:769:28)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1023:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/bislem/projects/test/electron/node_modules/dbus/lib/dbus.js:3:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1145:30)
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
Uncaught Exception:
Error: Module did not self-register: '/home/bislem/projects/test/electron/node_modules/dbus/build/Release/dbus.node'.
    at process.func [as dlopen] (electron/js2c/asar.js:140:31)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1196:18)
    at Object.func [as .node] (electron/js2c/asar.js:140:31)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:981:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:881:14)
    at Function.Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:769:28)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1023:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/bislem/projects/test/electron/node_modules/dbus/lib/dbus.js:3:13)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1145:30)
```

I searched for this error and tried some solutions but none of them worked (`npm rebuild`,`npm update`,delete the `node_modules` folder then `npm install`,use a diffrent version of node using the `nvm` command), but when runing each package by his own, (run `electron` using the start script `electron .`, and run `dbus` with `node script.js`) they works correctly.

and there was this when installing the `dbus` package :
[console when installing dbus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGBBV.png), [console when installing dbus part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/si378.png)

my package.json file :

```
{
    "name": "electrontest",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "script.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "electron script.js",
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
        "dbus": "^1.0.7",
        "electron": "^10.1.5"
    }
}
```

so my question is what is the correct way to Build/Run such code ? || how to use these two packages side by side ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run

```
npm install --save-dev electron-rebuild && npx electron-rebuild
```

More on using native node modules in electron [here](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules)